# Pulling values from nested maps

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, nested

Looked around SO and couldn't find quite what I needed. I am looking for a way to pull the key from the outside map and the value from the inside map for usin in an output statement. If I had one map I know I can pull the data I need from the inside map by using `insideMap[key]`. However, the `[] operator` does not seem to work in this implementation `((*itr).second)[keyword]`.

```
map< string, map<string, int> >::const_iterator itr; 
for( itr=books.begin(); itr!=books.end(); ++itr)
  //code I need here
```

Comment: `operator[]` modifies the map by inserting a new value if it doesn't already exist. So you can't use it with a `const_iterator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `[]` is `const`-ness of your iterator: the `[]` operator is not `const`, so you need to use `find(keyword)` instead, and dereference the iterator that it returns:

```
*(((*itr).second).find(keyword))
```

You could also switch to non-const iterator and use `[]`.

Comment: Thanks. I figured I didn't want to use a non-`const` iterator as I didn't want to mess up my maps. Then I realized I am not using my maps for anything else and that default constrution does more help than harm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use std::map::at() instead of operator[]. at() returns the value of a key like operator[], but there is a const version of at().

```
(itr->second).at(keyword)
```

The difference between at() and operator[] is that at() does an additional range check and throws an out_of_range exception if it fails.